# How would I write a concept for enforcing a class's method return type?

Tags: c++

Like I have a function in a class `Summation` like so

```
   void putsum(T args) {
         sum = args;
    }
```

I want to write a concept called Summable. Like so

```
template<typename T> 
concept Summable = requires(T a)
{
    requires std::regular<T>;
    requires std::erasable<typename T::value_type>;
    requires std::destructible<typename T::value_type>;
}
```

But I also want to check to see that `T.putsum` returns void, and is called with `args`.

How would I do that? And is this a good or bad use of C++ concepts?

Here's my full class

```
template <typename T> 
class Summer {
    private: 
    T sum;
 
    public:
    Summer<T>(T start) {
        sum = start; 
    }

    T getsum() const {
        return sum;
    }
    
    void putsum(T args) {
         sum = args;
    }

};
```

Comment: Where is the `T` in `T args` coming from? That's not what you're trying to constrain, right?

Comment: @FatihBAKIR I just added my class implementation at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a concept that can enforce a template type that has parameters `ArgTs...` to have a function called `putsum` that takes parameters of types `ArgTs...` and return `void` like so:

```
#include <concepts>

template <class... ArgTs, template <class...> class U>
concept Summable = requires (U<ArgTs...> t) {
    { t.putsum(std::declval<ArgTs>()...) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template <typename T> 
class Summer {
    private: 
    T sum;
 
    public:
    Summer<T>(T start) {
        sum = start; 
    }

    T getsum() const {
        return sum;
    }
    
    void putsum(T args) {
         sum = args;
    }
};

static_assert(Summable<int, Summer<int>>);

void take_summer(Summable<int> auto& s, int i) {
    s.putsum(i);
}

int main() {
    Summer<int> s(3);
    take_summer(s, 42);
}
```

Note that the concept has  `-> std::same_as<void>;` instead of  `-> void;`. Concepts talk about concepts, not concrete types! You can add more constraints to the concept, I only include the `putsum` part for brevity.